How do I map one array at random with no duplicates and also include an item from a repeating array?
I have a JSON file with data in it that I'm trying to map out.
 const randomCategories = []

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * categoryData.length)
    const randomCategory = categoryData[randomIndex]
    console.log(randomCategory)
    randomCategories.push(randomCategory)
  }

I only want 10 items from the categoryData array without any duplicates. I cannot get anything to work that removes duplicates or doesn't include them to begin with.
There's a second array as well:
  const colors = [
    {
      "gradient-start": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      "gredient-end": "rgb(139,0,0)"
    },
    {
      "gradient-start": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      "gredient-end": "rgb(0,0,139)"
    },
    {
      "gradient-start": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      "gredient-end": "rgb(184,134,11)"
    },
    {
      "gradient-start": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      "gredient-end": "rgb(0,100,0)"
    },
    {
      "gradient-start": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      "gredient-end": "rgb(0,139,139)"
    },
    {
      "gradient-start": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      "gredient-end": "rgb(139,0,139)"
    },
    {
      "gradient-start": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      "gredient-end": "rgb(233,140,0)"
    }
  ]

Colors does not need to be randomized, it's fine in the order it is in.
From there, I'm mapping out items from randomCategories into a grid of components for the data
 <div className="grid grid-rows-1 grid-flow-col w-[2360px] h-[233px] max-h-[233px] gap-x-3">
      {randomCategories.map((item) => (
        <CategoryCard key={item?.id} name={item?.name} image={item?.image} />
      ))}

    </div>

The idea is that I'll generate an array of 10 random, unique items from categoryData and display those 10 items in 10 CategoryCards. Each CategoryCard should have a color from the colors array in it, in the same order. So if it's red, green, blue, yellow, etc. once I reach the end of the colors array it repeats again; red, green, blue, yellow, etc. I'm not sure how to include the colors in the .map function or how I'd go about having that array repeat?
Attached picture is what I'm trying to accomplish:


Get random categories with Array#splice:


const categoryData = 'music software football books media health training sports nature science space biology evolution games programming'.match(/\S+/g);
const copy = categoryData.slice();
const randomCategories = Array.from({length:10}, (_, i) => copy.splice(Math.random() * copy.length | 0, 1)[0]);
randomCategories.forEach((c, i) => console.log(i+1, c));
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}



Then use a category index to pick a color (the colors could be randomized the same way as the categories):
<div className="grid grid-rows-1 grid-flow-col w-[2360px] h-[233px] max-h-[233px] gap-x-3">
      {randomCategories.map((item, i) => (
        // use colors[i] to pick a color and insert into the card's style
        // or pass the index to a card so it could select a color itself
        <CategoryCard key={item?.id} name={item?.name} image={item?.image} />
      ))}

    </div>



Would it be easier to export the colors to it's own json file and just copy/paste them a bunch to get them to repeat once I hit the last color?

@Ninety9Balloons yes, you can do that

For randomizing a list like shuffling cards, you can loop through the indexes and pick a random member of the remaining list to be that element.   If it isn't the same, swap it.   Then that element is set in stone and you repeat with the remaining list, randomly setting the first element in the remaining list to a random element in the remaining list and swapping (or staying the same if you randomly picked the first element out of all remaining elements).
For this we can create a third array with all indexes into your categoryData array and swap indexes without altering the original array,
then later use those indexes to pull values from the random positions in
categoryData.


// easy 26 element array
const categoryData = Array.from('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

// easy 3 element array
const colors = Array.from('rgb')

// array of [0, 1, 2, 3, ...] with indexes into categoryData
const indexes = categoryData.map((value, index) => index)

// last index we care about is 9, or the last element
// of the categoryData array, whichever is less, in case
// categoryData has less than 10 elements
const lastIndex = Math.min(9, categoryData.length - 1)

// loop through first up to 10 elements
for (let i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
  // set current element to random element from remaining list
  const swapIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (lastIndex - i)) + i

  // swap if it wasn't randomly the same element
  if (swapIndex !== i) {
    const temp = indexes[i]
    indexes[i] = indexes[swapIndex]
    indexes[swapIndex] = temp
  }
}

// take first 10 random indexes as 'index' and
// index as 'i' (0-9), and map 'index' into categoryData
// and i into colors
var results = indexes.slice(0, 10).map((index, i) => ({ 
  data: categoryData[index],
  color: colors[i % colors.length]
}))

console.log(results)




Here's how I'd approach this.


// since every gradient uses the same starting color (full transparent), we can just enumerate the ending colors
const colors = [
  "rgb(139,0,0)",
  "rgb(0,0,139)",
  "rgb(184,134,11)",
  "rgb(0,100,0)",
  "rgb(0,139,139)",
  "rgb(139,0,139)",
  "rgb(233,140,0)"
];
  
function CategoryCard(props) {
  console.log("props", props);
  var heightAndWidth = {
    height: '180px',
    width: '180px'
  };
  var overlayStyle = {
    background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%, ' + props.color + ' 90%)',
    ...heightAndWidth
  };
  return (
    <div class="categoryCard" id={'category-' + props.id} style={heightAndWidth}>
      <img src={props.image} style={heightAndWidth}/>
      <span class="categoryOverlay" style={overlayStyle}>
        <span class="categoryName">
          {props.name}
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}

function CategoryBar() {
  // replace with your Ajax call. For testing, I just grabbed a bunch of stuff from Imgur.
  const categoryData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Roguelike', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/qUH5uosb.jpg'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'Tactical', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/46LyFDrb.jpg'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'Fighting', image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/1d/SF2_JPN_flyer.jpg/220px-SF2_JPN_flyer.jpg'}, 
    {id: 4, name: 'Casual', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/bM4D2wqg.jpg'}, 
    {id: 5, name: 'Simulation', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/j38ujfsg.jpg'}, 
    {id: 6, name: 'Survival', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/ZFxNZg6.jpeg'}, 
    {id: 7, name: 'Arcade', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/ziVyY1x.jpeg'}, 
    {id: 8, name: 'Sports', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/dR4zSIB.jpeg'}, 
    {id: 9, name: 'FPS', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/hKJafTq.png'}, 
    {id: 10, name: 'Platformer', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/6b6aze6.png'}, 
    {id: 11, name: 'Battle Royale', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/zOELMDZ.jpeg'}, 
    {id: 12, name: 'MMORPG', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/njgnDAF.jpeg'}, 
    {id: 13, name: 'Brawler', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/702TeW2g.jpg'}, 
    {id: 14, name: 'Tower defense', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/frVfXny.png'}, 
    {id: 15, name: 'World building', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/I1q0573.jpeg'}, 
    {id: 16, name: 'Rhythm', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/4dlUl3F.png'}, 
    {id: 17, name: 'Puzzle', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/U5YPpaa.png'}, 
    {id: 18, name: 'Sandbox', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/o1Rwwnu.jpeg'}, 
    {id: 19, name: 'Driving', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/zZ47HTT.jpeg'}, 
    {id: 20, name: 'RTS', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/yXM3vsm.jpeg'}, 
  ];

  const randomCategories = [];
  var categoryCount = Math.min(10, categoryData.length);
  while (randomCategories.length < categoryCount) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * categoryData.length);
    const randomCategory = categoryData.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    randomCategories.push(randomCategory[0]);
  }

  // size=160 below controls the size of the tiles
  // using the map index with a modulo operator to cycle through colors
  return (
    <div class="categoryBar">
      {randomCategories.map((item, index) => (
        <CategoryCard key={item.id} id={item.id} size={160}
                      name={item.name} image={item.image}
                      color={colors[index % colors.length]} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <CategoryBar />
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
body {
  /* you'll want to specify an actual font here */
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.categoryBar {
  background-color: #223355; /* not quite the same as your background color, but close */
  overflow-x: auto; /* show a scrollbar if it's too wide */
  overflow-y: hidden; /* don't show a scrollbar if it's too tall; just cut it off */
  white-space: nowrap; /* don't wrap tiles to the next line */
}

.categoryCard {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px; /* a bit of space between each tile */
  position: relative; /* allow absolute positioning within the tiles (for the gradient overlay and the title) */
  white-space: wrap; /* turn wrapping back on for longer titles */
}

.categoryCard img {
  object-fit: cover; /* don't stretch/squish images */
}

.categoryOverlay {
  /* position this precisely on top of its parent categoryCard element */
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.categoryName {
  bottom: 20px; /* space between text and bottom of card */
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* don't allow the text to go beyond the card boundary */
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>




In case anyone cares: the downvote (current score -1) came before a significant edit that (IMO) vastly improves the quality and usefulness of my answer.

Replace the for loop with a while loop, then only add the items that you haven't already extracted:
  const randomCategories = []

  let i = 0;
  while (randomCategories.length < 10) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * categoryData.length)
    const randomCategory = categoryData[randomIndex]
    console.log(randomCategory)
    if (!randomCategories.find(el => el['gradient-start'] === randomCategory['gradient-start'] && el['gradient-end'] === randomCategory['gradient-end']) {
      randomCategories.push(randomCategory)
    }
  }


Easier than trying to check whether an item has already been chosen, is to make a sacrificial clone copy of the source array, and delete each item as it is picked, then discard any remainder at the end.
